# Elasticities and exponents

Tags: mathematical-economics, elasticity

Given the following 3 equations:
$$
Y^*_t=100+3t \\
Y_t = Y_t^* (1+(0.2 (\sin t)) \\
B_t=B_t^* (1+(0.4 (\sin t)) \\
$$
And take B* to be the following, but is unknown:
$$
B_t^*= \alpha Y_t^* \\
$$
I've figured the best way to estimate B* is the following:
$$
\hat{B} _t^*=B_t (Y_t^*/Y_t )^{0.4/0.2} \\
$$
But I can't figure how it works. Can anyone provide a step-by-step? Also why is it not a perfect estimate?

---

**3 knowns**

[image]

---

**Estimate of unknown**

[image]